# \xrightarrow: position of text over an arrow should be lower

Tags: math-mode, positioning, arrows, overlays

The following example of LaTeX code

```
\documentclass[b4paper,oneside, final, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=2.9cm, left=2.1cm, right=2.1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \noindent\textbf{\large Algebraic Morse Theory:} Let $R$ be any ring. A 
\emph{based $R$-complex}, is a chain $R$-complex $(A_\star,\partial_\star)$, 
together with a chosen decomposition $A_n\!=\bigoplus_{i\in I_n}\!\!\!A_{n,i}$ 
for every $n$. Then $\partial_{n,i,j}\!=\!\partial_{i,j}$ denotes the $R$-module 
homomorphism $A_{n,i} \smash{\overset{\iota}{\longrightarrow}} 
A_n \smash{\overset{\partial_n}{\longrightarrow}}A_{n-1} 
\smash{\overset{\pi}{\longrightarrow}}A_{n-1,j}$, where $\iota$ is the coordinate inclusion and 
$\pi$ is the coordinate projection. The associated digraph of $A_\star$, 
$\Gamma_{\!A_\star}\!=\!\Gamma$, is a directed simple graph whose vertices are 
the indices from all $I_n$, and directed edges correspond to nonzero maps 
$\partial_{i,j}$. Each edge $(i,j)$ will be denoted by $i\!\to\!j$.\\[2mm]

    \noindent\textbf{Conclusion:} Given a based $R$-complex $(A_\star,\partial_\star,I_\star)$,
 any Morse matching $\mathcal{M}$ on $\Gamma_{\!A_\star}$ induces a homotopy 
equivalence between complexes $(A_\star,\partial_\star)$ and 
$(\mathring{A}_\star,\mathring{\partial}_\star)$, more precisely $A_\star
\xrightarrow{\pi\text{ s.d.r. }}\pi(A_\star) = \pi(\mathring{A}_\star)
\xleftarrow{\pi=p^{-1}\,\cong}\mathring{A}_\star$, and therefore isomorphisms 
$H_n(A_\star,\partial_\star) \cong H_n(\mathring{A}_\star,\mathring{\partial}_\star)$ 
for all $n\!\in\!\mathbb{Z}$. In particular, if $\mathcal{M}^0_{n-1}\!= 
\emptyset =\!\mathcal{M}^0_{n+1}$ then there holds $H_n(A_\star,\partial_\star) 
\cong  \mathring{A}_n$.
\end{document}
```

produces [image] (\iota, \partial, \pi are too high) instead of [image]. Furthermore, it produces [image] instead of (lowered text) [image]

or even better (lowered text and better overlay with p) [image].

Is there a way to create a better command `\xrightarrow` (and if possible, also `\xleftarrow`, `\xRightarrow`, `\xLeftarrow`, etc.), that positions the text better, like in the pictures above? The style in the second and fifth pics is most desirable. Also, I would be most happy if this command had an optional argument `[...]` that specified offset from the line of the arrow (including negative space).

P.S. By the way, is there a way to make the + and - sign in sub and superscripts appear with less space left and right of it? For example, -1 in the above picture is too far away from p.

Comment: When making an example it helps if you make a _Minimal_ example that demonstrates the problem, your posted example loads dozens of unrelated packages

Comment: i beg to differ with the very low positioning of the embellishment `\pi=p...` in the last two examples -- the arrow should *never* cut through the descender of the text above.  any good math editor (person) would immediately mark that for correction!  and "interrupting" the arrow as in the last example is entirely wrong.  while i might agree that this text is higher than desirable, it's definitely desirable that text over all arrows be aligned on the same baseline, which the `\delta_n` is definitely not.  you're treading here on hundreds of years of practice.

Comment: You are using many obsolete,duplicating, and/or conflicting packages: `mathtools` loads `amsmath`,  `tikz` and possibly others load `xcolor` in the background which is better than `color`. `tocloft` has a `subfigure` option which is meant to be used with `subfigure` package but that's obsolote and  `subfig` superseded it .... But as @DavidCarlisle mentions, to be able to help you I need to install all of these packages just to see that arrow placement which is just pointless.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: It is worse to have p so high than to have it cut through the arrow line, because then the whole line has additional vertical spacing. It is fine if your solution had text over all arrows aligned on the same baseline, it just has to be lower, preferably in a way that I can specify spacing. Hundreds of years? You mean 10-15? I don't see why interrupting the arrow is so bad.

Comment: @LeonLampret -- i *do* mean hundreds of years. before the 1970s, most good math typesetting was done with metal type. what you are asking for was, if not impossible, then seriously in need of special handwork involving manual reshaping of physical metal type. "cold type" ("variable" typewriters) came into play in the 1950s, but not for high-end math publications; your next-to-last (overprinted) example would have been possible with that, but not the "interrupted" arrow shaft. similarly with photo-type, starting in the late 1960s. and the poor quality of photo-type is why we have tex now.

Comment: Hope this is a better posed question.

Comment: I agree that the text _might_ sit a bit lower on the arrow (such that `\xrightarrow{x_p^q}` is still just above the arrow). However, if your issue is increased lineskip and you use a lot of inline math, I suggest adding `\linespread{1.08}` into your preamble, which will make all the line a bit looser. This way you'd get a more pleasant result I think.

Comment: Although I do agree that Leon's wishes are not "typesetting canon" I like the way it looks and thus +1'ed this question. Furthermore I'd like to add that at the moment the `xrightarrow` (`xleftarrow`) command does not really align its (actual) text on the same baseline. If you look closely at the to `\pi`s ontop of the arrows in his third image you will notice that they have a different vertical distance from their respective arrow. His proposed style contains less whitespace than the standard LaTeX result (and the `\pi`s have the same vertical offset) and thus is more appeasing (for me).

Comment: I'd say you have a far more serious typographic problem to solve than lowering the material set above the long arrows: your document's extremely long *measure* (aka line length). The long measure makes it rather difficult to read (as well as quite uninviting to even get started). You may seriously want to consider cutting the line length by 20 to 40 percent; your readers will certainly thank you.

Comment: @Mico: The document type b4 was chosen specifically with the intent of squeezing a lot on a single page, just like in *A Singular Introduction to Commutative Algebra* or Pete Clark's notes *Commutative Algebra*. I never write jibber-jabber and I always want my text to go straight to the point. For a newcomer, this certainly might be too dense, but readers who are not willing to carefully read every line are not serious anyway, hence irrelevant. I like dense text, so that a proof of an important theorem is contained on a single page. It's much more clear, though perhaps oveewhelming at first.

Comment: I think you've missed my point. Avoiding jibber-jabber and getting straight to the point are necessary but, alas, not sufficient criteria for effective communication. By employing such an inordinately long measure, you're making it needlessly hard for your readers to take in what you're trying to convey, i.e., you're creating a distraction. One way to address this issue, while still using a b4 paper size, would be to use a two-column format for your document. If you're skeptical: How many *good* print newspapers do you read that utilize a single-column format?

Comment: @Mico: You're right about the newspapers, but they are not mathematical text. I realize many people might not like my style. However, when I read books and it takes 10 pages to get to the relevant definition, I lose interest. Having such long lines has advantages: mathematical formulas are not 'broken up'; many sentences only take one line and are not 'broken up'; etc. I write the way I like to read. Anyway, I'd appreciate any help regarding `\xrightarrow`.

Answer (score 8):

I wrote some functions that allow to lower/raise the text under/above `xrightarrow` arrows. It seams that the text typeset using these macros is a little wider but it doesn't look too bad ;)

The code required is:

```tex
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xargs}

\newcommandx{\yaHelper}[2][1=\empty]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\empty}}%
  { \ensuremath{ \scriptstyle{ #2 } } } % no offset
  { \raisebox{ #1 }[0pt][0pt]{ \ensuremath{ \scriptstyle{ #2 } } } }  % with offset
}

\newcommandx{\yrightarrow}[4][1=\empty, 2=\empty, 4=\empty, usedefault=@]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{\empty}}
  { \xrightarrow{ \protect{ \yaHelper[ #4 ]{ #3 } } } } % there's no text below
  { \xrightarrow[ \protect{ \yaHelper[ #2 ]{ #1 } } ]{ \protect{ \yaHelper[ #4 ]{ #3 } } } } % there's text below
}

\newcommandx{\yleftarrow}[4][1=\empty, 2=\empty, 4=\empty, usedefault=@]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{\empty}}
  { \xleftarrow{ \protect{ \yaHelper[ #4 ]{ #3 } } } } % there's no text below
  { \xleftarrow[ \protect{ \yaHelper[ #2 ]{ #1 } } ]{ \protect{ \yaHelper[ #4 ]{ #3 } } } } % there's text below
}

\newcommandx{\yRightarrow}[4][1=\empty, 2=\empty, 4=\empty, usedefault=@]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{\empty}}
  { \xRightarrow{ \protect{ \yaHelper[ #4 ]{ #3 } } } } % there's no text below
  { \xRightarrow[ \protect{ \yaHelper[ #2 ]{ #1 } } ]{ \protect{ \yaHelper[ #4 ]{ #3 } } } } % there's text below
}

\newcommandx{\yLeftarrow}[4][1=\empty, 2=\empty, 4=\empty, usedefault=@]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{\empty}}
  { \xLeftarrow{ \protect{ \yaHelper[ #4 ]{ #3 } } } } % there's no text below
  { \xLeftarrow[ \protect{ \yaHelper[ #2 ]{ #1 } } ]{ \protect{ \yaHelper[ #4 ]{ #3 } } } } % there's text below
}
```

Usage is: `yrightarrow[<TEXT-BELOW>][<OFFSET-BELOW>]{<TEXT-ABOVE>}[<OFFSET-ABOVE>}` and similarly for the others.
A working minimal example looks like this:

```tex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xargs}

\newcommandx{\yaHelper}[2][1=\empty]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\empty}}%
  { \ensuremath{ \scriptstyle{ #2 } } } % no offset
  { \raisebox{ #1 }[0pt][0pt]{ \ensuremath{ \scriptstyle{ #2 } } } }  % with offset
}   

\newcommandx{\yrightarrow}[4][1=\empty, 2=\empty, 4=\empty, usedefault=@]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{\empty}}
  { \xrightarrow{ \protect{ \yaHelper[ #4 ]{ #3 } } } } % there's no text below
  { \xrightarrow[ \protect{ \yaHelper[ #2 ]{ #1 } } ]{ \protect{ \yaHelper[ #4 ]{ #3 } } } } % there's text below
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        A \yrightarrow{\pi \, \text{s.d.r.}}[-2pt] B \, , \: C \yrightarrow[\pi \, \text{s.d.r.}][4pt]{\pi \, \text{s.d.r.}}[-2pt] D
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example Result (Cutout)]

However, this seems to be a brute force approach and I don't know whether there may be any side-effects (also I'm not doing any math-size checks, the stuff above and below the arrow will be always set in `scriptstyle`). And of course it is a "dumb" solution because one has to determine the offset manually. And finally there's no support for the feature suggested by the fifth image.

I'd advise you to accept this answer not (yet) because I hope that somebody can provide a better solution (hopefully including the feature suggested by the fifth image, which possibly could be achieved by printing first the content with a slightly larger font and white colour and then overprint the actual content in black).

Comment: What's `\protect{` for?

Comment: Without the `protect` the code yields the error `ERROR: Argument of \\yaHelper has an extra }.` Some google'ing showed that this is the result of putting a _fragile_ command in a _moving argument_, which can be resolved be enclosing the whole thing in `protect`.